# Can not add user with Gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I am newby with gitolite.
I've install gitolite on a remote server.

```
http://dev.remoteserver.com
```

So I could git-cloning gitolite-admin.git.

```
git clone ssh://gitolite@dev.remoteserver.com/gitolite-admin.git
```

I wanted to add user and repo using gitolite. following is ordinary add user process.

---

In the local repository, 
conf / keydir directory exists.

```
open conf/gitolite.conf
```

added below text.

```
repo   aproject
       RW+ = testid
```

and, 
in local-mac,

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa.
```

added the public key in keydir/testid.pub
and then, git add / git commit / git push is done well.

---

okay, then I tried to cloning the fresh git repo from the remote server.

```
git clone ssh://testid@dev.remoteserver.com/aproject.git
```

but,it makes error like this...

```
mac$ git clone ssh://testid@dev.remoteserver.com/aproject.git
Cloning into 'aproject'...
mac@dev.remoteserver.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
mac@dev.remoteserver.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
mac@dev.remoteserver.com's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I think git cloning  shoud not ask password. 
and correct password also failed git-cloning.

My remote server is CentOS.

and comments welcomes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `gitolite`, all your ssh communications are done with the account used to install `gitolite`.
In your case: `gitolite`.

However, you can specify a *different* public key in order to indicate `gitolite` to authenticate you against a different user.
The ssh session will still be performed as `gitolite`.
But the name passed to `gitolite` script will be `testid` (because the public key was registered by `gitolite` in its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` as '`testid`')

So use a `~testid/.ssh/config` file in which you mention the right parameter:

```
Host gitolitesrv
Hostname dev.remoteserver.com
User gitolite
IdentityFile /path/to/tesitd
```

Note that `/path/to/` must contain your private key `testid` and your public key `testid.pub`.
At this point, their name isn't important (could be `xxx` and `xxx.pub`)
What *was* important was the name of the public key as stored in `gitolite-admin/keydir/testid.pub` (because the name of the file is used for the id recorded in the [`authorized_keys` forced-command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) line)

And then, this `git clone` should work:

```
git clone gitolitesrv:aproject.git
```

---

The [OP Jinbom Heo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505345/jinbom-heo) mentions having difficulties:

Cloning into 'aproject'... 
R access for aproject DENIED to gitolite
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?) 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

> it appears that git user is not `testid` but `gitolite`.

```
Host dev2git 
  Hostname dev.remoteserver.com 
  User gitolite 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/testid
```

> And a `gitolite.conf` file include the following (git-pushed):

repo aproject 
  RW+ = testid

> At last, I found the reason.
>   **When generating ssh-key using ssh-keygen, I typed password**. That's the problem.
>   So I tried keygen without password, and it works~. I don't know why password should not be added when I make the key. Anyway, It works well

---

I can confirm I have always use **passphrase-less keys**.
I you do want to protect your keys with passphrase, see "[appendix 1: ssh daemon asks for a password](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sts.html#stsapp1_)"

> make sure you're being asked for a password and not a passphrase.
>   Do not confuse or mistake a prompt saying Enter passphrase for key '`/home/sitaram/.ssh/id_rsa`': for a password prompt from the remote server!
>
> When you create an `ssh keypair` using `ssh-keygen`, you have the option of protecting it with a passphrase.
>   **When you subsequently use that `keypair` to access a remote host, your local `ssh` client needs to unlock the corresponding private key, and `ssh` will probably ask for the passphrase you set when you created the `keypair`**.
>
> You have two choices to avoid this prompt every time you try to use the private key.
>
> - The first is to create keypairs without a passphrase (just hit enter when prompted for one).
>     Be sure to add a passphrase later, once everything is working, using `ssh-keygen -p`.
> - The second is to use `ssh-agent` (or `keychain`, which in turn uses `ssh-agent`) or something like that to manage your keys.
>     Other than discussing one more potential trouble-spot with `ssh-agent` (see "[appendix 3: ssh client may not be offering the right key](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sts.html#stsapp3_)"), further discussion of `ssh-agent/keychain` is out of scope of this document.

Comment: thank you for you detail answer. I've tried your process. but failed. the error message is this. ///// Cloning into 'aproject'...
R access for aproject DENIED to gitolite
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly ///// 
it appears that git user is not testid but gitolite.

Comment: my config file is like this ///// 
Host dev2git
Hostname dev.remoteserver.com
User gitolite
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/testid
/////
and gitolite.conf file include the following. (git-pushed) /////
repo  aproject
 RW+  =   testid  /////

Comment: At last, I found the reason. 
When generating ssh-key using ssh-keygen, I typed password. That's the  problem. So I tried keygen without password, and it works~. 
I don't know why password should not be added when I make the key.
Anyway, It works well.

Comment: @JinbomHeo: thank you for your feedback and sorry for the delay (I just woke up). I have including your conclusion in the answer for more visibility, and I have added some documentation regarding ssh keys and passphrase.

Comment: +1 specifying that the user in ~/.ssh/config needs to be 'gitolite' (or equivalent) EVEN if you are trying to authenticate as a different user at a repo level. Wish I'd found this an hour ago... :-) obvious when you think about it though!

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble cloning out the `gitolite-admin` repository after the initial setup and it was due to the fact that I gave group write permissions to the home folder of the gitolite user `git` and `ssh` doesn't like that.

---

I checked Check `/var/log/secure` and saw this :

> Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/git

So all I had to do was :

`sudo chmod g-w /home/git/`

#### References :

- http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/
- http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh.html