# git write and read access without beeing user of server

Tags: git, security, ssh-keys

i was searching for a while, but couldn't find a fitting solution:
My Case:

I have a server on which i have a git repository. The connection to the server is only possible with fitting ssh key.
Is there a possibility to give a user, who hasn't access to the server, permissions to write and read from this specific repository?

Is there only the possibility by creating a user account for the user on the server or can i do it different? OF course i only want him to read/write to the repo, but i dont want him to see what is going on beyond this repository on the server?

Hopefully this is not to much thought outside the box?!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had on the server the ***[authorization](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html)*** layer **[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**, you will be able to register that external user ssh public key, giving him/her access to one one specific repository (as configure in your [gitolite configuration file](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/exbac.html))

[image: Gitolite]

(from the blog post "[SSH and the Gitolite Installation – part 2](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/10/18/ssh-and-the-gitolite-installation-part-2/)")

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what i was searching for!!! Though it took me a couple of hours to figure out, i cannot use the same ssh-key  for the git user and gitolite :-) and second: the [link](git clone git@server:gitolite-admin) didnt work for me. I dont even know if this is supposed to work, cause tha gitolite-admin folder is in the subfolder repositories, so what worked for me was: [link](git clone git@server:port/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin) Maybe gitolite wiki is not up to date!

Comment: @NewYearsEve gitolite wiki is very much up-to-date, and `git clone git@server:port/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin` is very-very-*very* wrong: you just by-passed gitolite entirely, as described in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sts.html#ssh_troubleshooting_common_ssh_problems_

Comment: @NewYearsEve: `git@server:gitolite-admin` is an scp syntax (a way to define a shortcut for ssh URI scheme), working in conjunction with a `~/.ssh/config` file: see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630937/can-not-add-user-with-gitolite/9633439#9633439

Comment: thanks again, you are right, i was not allowed to push into the remote repository the way i did it. So i removed the one ssh-key which was before gitolite start and now it is working as discribed in the wiki. Sorry for the wrong comment!!