# Adding Users to Gitolite, Permission Denied

Tags: linux, git, gitolite, public-key

I have a Gitolite server running on EC2 that works pretty well. I've added users before and have no problem adding repositories.

My Macbook Pro can push code to a repository with no problem (it has the `RW+` permission on the repo). I've also added a second computer to the repository with `R` permissions so I can clone it.

The issue is, I keep getting "Permission Denied (public key)" when trying to clone the repo. When I SSH into the server with Gitolite and look at the user "git"'s authorized_keys file, I *do* see the public key of the second computer, so I'm not sure what the problem is-- it looks like it is getting added just fine. The public key of the second computer is also located under `keydir` with the appropriate name (`raspberry.pub`)

Here's my gitolite conf, with some info changed to protect privacy:

```
repo    statistics-app
        RW+     =   andrew
        R       =   raspberry
```

Note: "andrew" can push code and clone the repo just fine, but the user "raspberry" cannot. What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have, on your second computer, a `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
host gitolite-raspberry
     user git
     hostname raspberry
     identityfile ~/.ssh/raspberry
```

(See, for instance, "[Can not add user with Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630937/can-not-add-user-with-gitolite/9633439#9633439)")

You need to check if `ssh gitolite-raspberry` answers you with the Gitolite rights associated with the `raspberry` ssh account.

If not, `ssh -vvv gitolite-raspberry` will provide you with clues.

---

The [OP Andrew M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480033/andrew-m) reports a right issue:

> **I didn't set the permissions of the folder I was cloning into**, so I "sudoed" the git command.
>   The root user on the Raspberry Pi wasn't allowed to clone, so it failed.

Comment: Actually, in my case, it turns out it was a stupid mistake on my part. I didn't set the permissions of the folder I was cloning into, so I "sudoed" the git command. The root user on the Raspberry Pi wasn't allowed to clone, so it failed.

Comment: @AndrewM ok, I have included it in the answer. I would like to know, though, if you are using a `~/.ssh/config` file for your ssh repo addresses. I find those very convenient to be sure to use the right ssh user and ssh keys.

Comment: At the moment, I am not. I don't believe I am on any of the computers with permission to access the Git server...

Comment: @AndrewM: Note, the `config` file I am referring about is on your *client*. Not on the Git server. You would use it for your remote repo ssh addresses.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was referring to. There definitely isn't one on the server and AFAIK there are no config files on any of the clients.